# Linear interpolation of points in isometric isomorphic spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that we have two spaces $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ and we know that $\mathcal{H}$ is isometric isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}$, so that distances and angles are preserved. Note that we are also given the mapping from one space to the other ($\Phi$).

Then, if I do a linear interpolation between two points $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ of $\mathcal{H}$ so that: 
$$\mathbf{x}_\mathrm{new} = \mathbf{x}_1 + (\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1)\cdot \delta $$
where $\delta$ is some constant.

Is there any way to verify that if I compute the map of $\mathbf{x}_\mathrm{new}$ from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{F}$ it will be a linear interpolation of $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ in $\mathcal{F}$ as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the line segments joining  $\mathbf x_1$ to $\mathbf x_2$ and to $\mathbf x_{\text{new}}$.  "Linear interpolation" as you described it, means that the angle between them is $0$, and the length of the latter is $\delta$ times the length of the former.  Your hypotheses say that this information is preserved by $\Phi$.